# Where is the latest version of Hiero

Tags: android, libgdx

I have google searched first, and downloaded the version that is linked [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1247) but it is missing the DistanceField option that is mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/DistanceFieldFonts)

Anybody know a good place to get a version of Hiero that has the DistanceField option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from somebody in the libgdx forums (see http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8932)

You have to download the code from github
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

Then follow these steps to build the project from source
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SourceBuilding

Import all into eclipse and you will find hiero in the tools folder